# I'm stuck in an endless loading screen. Is this normal?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-ds

I have a Nintendo DS with a [DSOne Flash Card with EOS](http://eng.supercard.sc/manual/dsone/evolution/) installed on it.

[image: DSOneCard and MicroSD]

Before the software update, it works completely fine.

Just recently, I've managed to find an software update. However, after the update - It seems to be stuck in an endless loading screen.

[image: Endless loading screen]

There's several things that were suggested to do to find the problem, such as using the troubleshooter (holding <kbd>LT</kbd> and <kbd>RT</kbd> while the DS is starting), but it is to avail.
In case, here's the results:

[image: Results]

```
Test Flash
flash id ok!
flash ok!

Test sd card
sd ok! no find test file.

Test Psram
psram ok!

Now SuperCard DS Version:
English Ver1.01

Test finished.
```

Is there something else that I'm missing? Am I using the wrong EOS version for my card? Is there any other update steps I missed?

Comment: Unauthorized software, while not illegal, is kind of a, "use at your own risk" sorta deal.

Comment: Just a note - the last two images are upside down.

Comment: Um.. I realised @AshleyNunn. I'm going to flip it next period (in 50mins)

Comment: Cool beans, just wanted to point it out in case you missed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you do make sure you are using the right version for your card and that you removed the previous files required on the SD card so that only the new files are there, otherwise version conflicts may occur. You didn't specify your update method and as I recall this card had two options: one to simply rewrite files on the SD card, and another using a special update adapter.

I would suggest also trying to download and update the files from a different computer or internet connection if you have occasional issues with your ISP as many people do these days it is possible your download was actually corrupted but not in a way that your computer detected.

Comment: Which one should I try using (based on what you've seen of the card?)

Comment: id try the easiest method first download any packs they have for the upgrade firmware and keep each seperate, use a fresh sd card and try each, one at a time.

Comment: personally I like cyclods better and anything that has a port2 expansion cart compatibility is always nicer presuming you have a dslite....this can enable more modern tech as is acts as a  coprocessor and ram storage to my understanding....

Comment: there are 3 different possibilities on the site presuming you are using an american card you do not want to use the software with the (chs)at the end as this is likely chinese. if you dont have the usb firmware writer you most likely couldnt have damaged the card permanently but removing it when it is writing still or having an accidental power loss could in theory if it actually writes to some internal controller if this has such....

Comment: http://down.supercard.sc/download/evolution/DSONE_Evolution_V1.0_eng_sp6_20130129.zip is the first one I would try as it is the most recent being 2013 as opposed to 2012...

Comment: ... That worked. Now: I can't change the downvote to an upvote.

Comment: please click the checkmark next to my answer so I can get credit for the proper answer.